# Mobile menu - hamburger icon - 'hover' color not changing and 'focus' on links not working

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu

I would like my hamburger icon on my mobile menu to turn black on Hover and my links on my dropdown menu to turn black in Focus mode so people could see which page is active.

This is the first website I have ever attempted, it is my own website (small business). I used wordpress and oceanwp as the theme. Also used Elementor to style the pages.
I have learned a lot about css and managed to use it for other details.
I also learned how to inspect elements with google Chrome inspect, and this is the method I was trying to use to get the css required to fix these issues.
I have been trying for a long while now and I could not manage, so that is why I have decided to seek help through this forum.
Please, please could some one inspect my website in google Chrome and find out how to fix it? My website is:

santacruzingeniorkonsulent.no

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by hover? A hover event is something that is triggered by a cursor but there is no cursor is mobile.  

Also, please provide a snippet of the code you attempted so we can build off that.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the theme you are using there should be an option under the Customize tab, use it and navigate to your theme's header settings, from there you will find styling options for mobile menu's
Or under the theme color options there should be a link/link hover color option